# Redshift Check if the value of current record exists in next partition

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to create a SQL statement without using self join on the table to check if value of current record exists in next partition
EX:
**Input_Table**

```
userid|       time          | product  
    -----|---------------------|-----

      1  | 2020-01-10 8:00:00  | A
      1  | 2020-01-10 9:00:00  | B
      1  | 2020-01-10 9:00:00  | A
      1  | 2020-01-10 10:00:00 | C
      1  | 2020-01-10 10:00:00 | B
      1  | 2020-01-10 11:00:00 | D
      1  | 2020-01-10 11:00:00 | E
      1  | 2020-01-10 11:00:00 | A
```

**Output_Table**

```
userid|       time          | product | Is_Repeated?
    -----|---------------------|-----|---------

      1  | 2020-01-10 8:00:00  | A  | 1
      1  | 2020-01-10 9:00:00  | B  | 1
      1  | 2020-01-10 9:00:00  | A  | 0
      1  | 2020-01-10 10:00:00 | C  | 0
      1  | 2020-01-10 10:00:00 | B  | 1
      1  | 2020-01-10 11:00:00 | D  | 0
      1  | 2020-01-10 11:00:00 | B  | 0
      1  | 2020-01-10 11:00:00 | A  | 0
```

Below is what I am trying but it looks for next record in partition instead of every record in next partition and returns 0 in my flag for every record.

```
SELECT userid, time, product, 
 CASE WHEN Lead(product) OVER (partition by userid order by time) = product THEN 1 else 0 END  as Is_Repeated?
FROM Input_table
```

Comment: What do YOU mean by "in the next partition"?

Comment: next partition is next timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Redo the query but order by product and time. For the flag you need one occurence, so if its repeated, you will get it:

This check only if there is repetition coming next

```
with Input_table as
(
select 1 as userid,'2020-01-10 8:00:00' as time, 'A' as product
union select 1  ,'2020-01-10 9:00:00', 'B'
union select  1  ,'2020-01-10 9:00:00', 'A'
union select  1  ,'2020-01-10 10:00:00', 'C'
union select   1  ,'2020-01-10 10:00:00', 'B'
union select   1  ,'2020-01-10 11:00:00', 'D'
union select  1 ,'2020-01-10 11:00:00', 'E'
union select  1  ,'2020-01-10 11:00:00', 'A' 
),
cte2 as
(
SELECT userid, "time", product, 
 CASE WHEN Lead(product) OVER (partition by userid order by product, time) = product THEN 1 else 0 END  as "Is_Repeated?"
FROM Input_table
)  
select * from cte2 order by time
```

if you want to flag all repeated use:

```
    with Input_table as
    (
    select 1 as userid,'2020-01-10 8:00:00' as time, 'A' as product
    union select 1  ,'2020-01-10 9:00:00', 'B'
    union select  1  ,'2020-01-10 9:00:00', 'A'
    union select  1  ,'2020-01-10 10:00:00', 'C'
    union select   1  ,'2020-01-10 10:00:00', 'B'
    union select   1  ,'2020-01-10 11:00:00', 'D'
    union select  1 ,'2020-01-10 11:00:00', 'E'
    union select  1  ,'2020-01-10 11:00:00', 'A' 
    ),
    cte2 as
    (
    SELECT userid, "time", product, 
     CASE WHEN Lead(product) OVER (partition by userid order by product, time) = product THEN 1 else 0 END  as "Is_Repeated?"
    FROM Input_table
    ),
 cte3 as
 (
    select userid, product, max("Is_Repeated?") as "Is_Repeated?" from cte2 group by userid, product
 )
 select a.userid, a.product, "time", "Is_Repeated?"
 from Input_table a inner join cte3 b on a.userid = b.userid and  a.product = b.product order by "time"
```

Comment: I tried both, if you look at A  its repeated from 8:00 to 9:00 this returns isrepeatedflag= 1 fine, but A in 9:00 does not repeat in 10:00 and it still returns isrepeatedflag= 1 instead for 9:00 timestamp only B should return isrepeatedflag =1

Comment: basically, I want to flag any line item true or 1 when in the next timestamp if there is a product value exists for same userid

Answer (score 0):

Based on your data, "next partition" appears to mean within about an hour.  If so, the logic would be:

```
SELECT userid, "time", product, 
       (CASE WHEN LEAD(time) OVER (partition by userid, product ORDER BY time) < time + INTERVAL '2 hour'
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END)  as "Is_Repeated?"
FROM Input_table;
```

Based on the clarification in your comment:

```
SELECT userid, "time", product, 
       (CASE WHEN LEAD(time) OVER (partition by userid, product ORDER BY time) =
                  LEAD(time) OVER (partition by userid ORDER BY time)
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END)  as "Is_Repeated?"
FROM Input_table;
```

Comment: Is it possible if its not always hour.. This is just a sample

Comment: @user1701450 . . . I fixed the answer.  `partition` already has multiple meanings in relational databases.  Your use of the word is confusing, but the comment clarifies what you want to do.  That information should go in the question as well.